# Persistence error after migrating from Hibernate 5.6 to 6

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

After migrating Quarkus 2.16 to 3 (and Hibernate 5.6 to 6) I got a bug in persisting data. Essentially my schema looks like this:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "owner",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<Pet> pets = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
class Pet {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "fkidperson",
                referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Person owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pet",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true,
               fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Food> foods = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
class Food {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "fkidpet",
                referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Pet pet;
}
```

and I will try to update it with a POST request containing

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John",
    "pets": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "Fuffy",
            "foods": []
        }
    ]
}
```

while on the backend I would like to overwrite the previous person using an `entityManager.merge(person)` but it fails with an

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier for collection of role (Pet.foods)
```

while before it was working.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I have seen a question very similar (if not exactly the same) yesterday (or few days ago) and the answer discovers a problem in mapping; search for this question (I'm currently unable to find it out)

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be because it is initializing the lists in the declaration.

Try it:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "owner",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<Pet> pets;
}

@Entity
class Pet {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "fkidperson",
                referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Person owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pet",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true,
               fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Food> foods;
}
```